# How could this code use the ValueError function

Tags: python, integer

```
if op == '+':
    left1 = random.randint(1,100)
    right1 = random.randint(1,100)
    print ("What is " + (str(left1) + op + str(right1) + "?"))
    answer  = eval(str(left1) + op + str(right1))
    guess = int(input(""))
    if guess == answer:
        print("Correct!")
        score + 1
    elif guess != answer:
        print("Incorrect")
    else:
        except ValueError:
            print("Expected integer")
```

I tried except ValueError, but it stated that it was invalid syntax. I'm trying to get the code to force the user to enter an integer for the answer, if they don't then it tells them that they are supposed to enter an integer.

Comment: You need to put your code (that you think may `ValueError` out) into a `try` block *before* the `except` block.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: why do you turn the `ints `to `strings` to add them?

Comment: @DanielJimenez: to create a valid Python expression in a string. It is redundant here because the code already determined that `op` is `+`, so you could just use `answer = left1 + right1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but why not `answer = left1 + right1`

Comment: @DanielJimenez: inexperience on the part of the OP, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError` is not a function; it is a class (an `Exception` subclass).

You need to use `except` as part of a `try` statement, it cannot be used on its own; you need to put any code you want 'protected' inside the `try`:

```
if op == '+':
    left1 = random.randint(1,100)
    right1 = random.randint(1,100)
    print ("What is " + (str(left1) + op + str(right1) + "?"))
    answer  = eval(str(left1) + op + str(right1))

    try:
        guess = int(input(""))
    except ValueError:
        print("Expected integer")
    else:    
        if guess == answer:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1  # don't forget to *store* the sum!
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
```

You probably want to read the canonical Stack Overflow question on user input in Python to learn more about this:  [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response), as well as the [section on handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the Python tutorial.